# BMA490l returns zeros if i read 6 bytes from register 0x12

Tags: python, accelerometer, i2c

i have trouble getting this to work. im using BMA409l acceleration sensor with raspberry pi zero w with i2c communication of 100khz. basically i want to get acceleration readings that should be from 0x12 to 0x17 according to the datasheet

[image: portion from datasheet]

but when i use this code

```
import smbus
bus=smbus.SMBus(1)
bus.read_i2c_block_data(0x18,0x12,6)
```

i just get

```
[0,0,0,0,0,0]
```

i'm sorry for the description this small, but to be honest i as well have little to no understanding whats going on. is the IC damaged? or is this problem caused by my lack of knowledge, as im kinda new in this field.

if you want you can see full [BMA490l datasheet here](https://www.bosch-sensortec.com/media/boschsensortec/downloads/datasheets/bst-bma490l-ds000.pdf)

Comment: "After power up sequence the accelerometer is in suspend mode" - there's a whole series of commands you need to issue before you can get any data, see the Device Initialization section of the datasheet.

Comment: thanks, looks like i was not initializing the unit as you said. oh and btw, what does that 15_8 and 7_0 mean in acc_x_*_*?

Comment: Those are the numbers of the bits (of the whole 16-bit value) contained in each byte.

Comment: thanks a lot. now everything makes way more sense

Comment: You need to read them as 2-bytes sequences (bulk transfers) and combine into 16-bit values.